# How to set tags while using reflect.New

Tags: pointers, go, struct, go-reflect

When creating a new struct from existing struct, tags are not set on the new struct.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
  Bar string `custom:"tag"`
}

func readTag(e interface{}) {
  t := reflect.TypeOf(e).Elem()
  f, _ := t.FieldByName("Bar")
  fmt.Println(f.Tag)
}

func main() {
  foo := &Foo{"baz"}

  fmt.Println(foo)
  readTag(foo)

  fooType := reflect.TypeOf(foo).Elem()
  newFoo := reflect.New(fooType).Elem()
  newFoo.FieldByName("Bar").SetString("baz2")
  fmt.Println(newFoo)
  readTag(&newFoo)// empty
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/7-zMPnwQ8Vo

How to set tags while using `reflect.New`? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags do not belong to instances, tags belong to types.

So when you create new instances of your type, their type will be the same "wearing" the same tags. It doesn't matter if you create new instances with literals or via the `reflect` package.

The problem in your case is that `newFoo` is of type `reflect.Value`, and `&newFoo` is of type `*reflect.Value`, it's not a pointer to your struct (not of type `*Foo`).

If you unwrap the struct value:

```
newFoo.Interface()
```

And you pass this, and you make the `Elem()` call optional (only do it if it's a pointer):

```
func readTag(e interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(e)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    f, _ := t.FieldByName("Bar")
    fmt.Println(f.Tag)
}
```

Then you'll get the same tag (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ieDAnmdmSvR)):

```
&{baz}
custom:"tag"
{baz2}
custom:"tag"
```

You get the same result if you keep the `reflect.Value` wrapping the struct pointer, and unwrap from it:

```
newFooPtr := reflect.New(fooType)
newFoo := newFooPtr.Elem()
newFoo.FieldByName("Bar").SetString("baz2")
fmt.Println(newFoo)
readTag(newFooPtr.Interface()) // empty
```

Then `readTag()` doesn't need to be modified. Try this version on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LWSye2KfLVT).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!